# POST call to Controller’s Method to save textbox data in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Good day! I am curretly working on a project wherein a user fills-up a form and a modal confirmation will pop-up. After verifying the details inside, the user will then click submit to save the data. I tried using [this](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html) tutorial about POST to controller to save my data in the database. Unfortunately, nothing happens after clicking the `Submit` button.

**Model**

```
public partial class Transaction
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string queue_no { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string address { get; set; }
public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Transactions(string Name, string Address,string QueueNo)
{
Transaction trans = new Transaction();
trans.name = Name;
trans.address = Address;
db.Transactions.Add(trans);
db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to submit the following details?
            <br/>
            <br />
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Queue Number</th>
                    <td id="queuenoo"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fullname</th>
                    <td id="namee"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <td id="addresss"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var url = "/Series/Transactions";
        var name = $("#namee").val();
        var address = $("#addresss").val();
        var queueno = $("#queuenoo").val();
        $.post(url, { Name: name, Address: address, QueueNo: queueno });
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td>` elements do not have a `value` attribute. You need to use `.text()` (or `.html()`)

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var url = "/Series/Transactions";
    var name = $("#namee").text();
    var address = $("#addresss").text();
    var queueno = $("#queuenoo").text();
    $.post(url, { Name: name, Address: address, QueueNo: queueno });
});
```